# How to get the names of non-contact member in a Skype group conversation?

Tags: skype

I want to know how to get the names of non-friends in multi-person conversation in web.skype.com.

For example: in a multi-person conversation, there is a user A who is not my contact, but the web.skype web page can display the name of user A. Through Chrome's network tools, I am only getting a conversation history message record request I have seen the name of user A, but if user A has not sent a message, all the data obtained by request does not contain the name of user A.

If anyone knows and tells me how to get it, I would appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Skype dont provide an API who can do that, you need to implement a bot to give you this information.

Comment: thanks for you replay, yes, i know skype doesnt supply this, but i just want to know how the web.skype.com show the name in the web page.  I mean,  it must get it from server via https/wss,  and it can be show in network in the chrome devtools. 
    I guess it is encrypted data, hidden in a request, and parsed out in the web client